# Self-Incremental ID for saving in MVC Springframework

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my Maven-based MVC Springframework project, I have a class named Rentals, which I've mapped to a PostgreSQL table of the same name. In it, I've configured the Id to be a Serial int, which increments automatically for every new entry.
My question is: How do I make it so that Spring knows that if it saves a new Rental object, it saves it with its predestined id?

Here is my Rentals java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rentals")
public class Rentals implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name="rentals_id_seq", sequenceName="rentals_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="rentals_id_seq")
private int id;

// Other column data

// Empty, only id, full and all except id constructors

// Getters and setters, hashcode, equals and tostring

}
```

My DAO implementation is very simple, which implements from a simple DAO interface and uses a `private SessionFactory sessionFactory` to realize the CRUD operations.

My Service implementation is also very simple, which implements a Service interface (which is an exact copy of the DAO interface) and uses a `private MurDao murDao` to realize the CRUDs.

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MurController {

private MurService murService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "murService")
public void setMurService(MurService murService) {
    this.murService = murService;
}

// other CRUDs for other entities

@RequestMapping(value = "/rentals", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRentals(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("rental", new Rentals());
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.murService.getUsers());
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", this.murService.getMovies());
    model.addAttribute("listRentals", this.murService.getRentals());
    return "rental";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/rentals/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRental(@ModelAttribute("rental") Rentals rnt) {

    try {
        this.murService.getRental(rnt.getId());
        this.murService.updateRental(rnt);
    } catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex) {
        this.murService.addRental(rnt);
    }

    return "redirect:/rentals";
}

@RequestMapping("/rentals/remove/{id}")
public String removeRental(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    this.murService.deleteRental(id);
    return "redirect:/rentals";
}

@RequestMapping("/rentals/edit/{id}")
public String editRental(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("rental", this.murService.getRental(id));
    model.addAttribute("listRentals", this.murService.getRentals());
    return "rental";
}
}
```

Finally, the .jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html><head><title>Rental Page</title><style type="text/css">.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#f0f0f0;}.tg .tg-4eph{background-color:#f9f9f9}</style></head>
<body>
    <c:url var="addAction" value="/rentals/add" ></c:url>

    <form:form action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="rental">
        <table>
            <tr><td>
                    <form:label path="iduser">
                        <spring:message text="ID User"/>
                    </form:label></td><td>
                    <form:select path="iduser">
                        <form:options items="${listUsers}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="fullName"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td></tr><tr><td>
                    <form:label path="idmovie">
                        <spring:message text="ID Movie"/>
                    </form:label></td><td>
                    <form:select path="idmovie">
                        <form:options items="${listMovies}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="title"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td></tr><tr><td>
                    <form:label path="dateof">
                        <spring:message text="Date Of"/>
                    </form:label></td><td>
                    <form:input path="dateof" cssClass="form-control"/></td><td>
                    <spring:message text="Please use dd-mm-yyyy" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add Rental"/>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </form:form> <br> <h3>Rentals List</h3>
    <c:if test="${!empty listRentals}"><table class="tg"><tr>
                <th>ID User</th>
                <th>ID Movie</th>
                <th>Date Of</th>
                <th width="60">Delete</th>
            </tr><c:forEach items="${listRentals}" var="rental"><tr>
                    <td>${rental.iduser}</td>
                    <td>${rental.idmovie}</td>
                    <td>${rental.dateof}</td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/rentals/remove/${rental.id}'/>" >Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table></c:if></body></html>
```

What is currently happening is that, whenever I set some information in the "add new rental" button, the .jsp sends through a new Rental Object, but it has an id of 0. I don't want this, I want to create a new Rental with an id of Null or something like that so that spring knows that it has to wait to know what number of id to give it given it is auto-generated and self-incremental.

How do I approach this? Why does the jsp sends through an object with id 0? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: primitive types (e.g. int) cannot be null. Try using the wrapper type: `private Integer id`; https://medium.com/@bpnorlander/java-understanding-primitive-types-and-wrapper-objects-a6798fb2afe9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alan Hay commented, an int primitive cannot be null. And it was exactly what I needed. Just after I switched all ints that deal with my Rental's id, this happened.

```
Información:   Rentals{id=null, iduser=testUser01, idmovie=testMovie01, dateof=Tue Jan 01 00:01:00 CST 2019}
Información:   Hibernate: select nextval ('rentals_id_seq')
Información:   Hibernate: insert into rentals (dateof, iduser, idmovie, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And it was saved to my database. Thanks a lot, Alan Hay!